# how to send live transaction to test server authorize.net via activemerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

I need to send my sample transactions as "live" transactions to the test gateway for authorize.net so that they show up in the reports on their website under my test account.  Test transactions are not processed and wont show up in the reports.

The problem is that when I connect to the gateway, I have to specify test mode to get to the test servers, and due to that (in the gateway commit code) all my purchase requests are sent across with the x_test_request parm.  I tried sending an option to the purchase method of { test: false } but that didn't work.

How can I do this?  I'm using ruby/rails (obviously).  Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I've seen when you add test:false to the gateway options that it then posts to the live url rather than the http://apitest.authorize.net:443/xml/v1/request.api url.  The test transactions return a transaction_id of 0 and I need a transaction_id so I can test refunds with the CIM

Answer (score 2):

Got it...  Had to fork and play around with the active_merchant gem to figure it out.

Connect to your CIM Gateway with the :test_requests=>false option.  This will prevent the

```
<extraOptions>x_test_request=TRUE</extraOptions>
```

from showing up in the XML.  So it should look like this (with your credentials)

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway.new({:login => AUTHNET_TEST_LOGIN, :password => AUTHNET_TEST_TRANS_KEY, :test_requests=>false})
```